# What is a good way to browse git commits locally with syntax highlighting?

Tags: git

What is a good way to browse git commits locally with syntax highlighting?

Basically, I want to do "git diff" between a particular commit a its previous commit, but with syntax highlighting supported.

Comment: for red/green adds/removals you can do git diff --color.   I think you might bean code highlighting though.

Comment: https://github.com/bernardofire/githat might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a pager that supports syntax highlighting. Vim could be used for this:

```
GIT_PAGER="vim -" git diff --no-color ...
```

`--no-color` turns off git-diff's own colouring, which would otherwise just show up as clutter (unless you have vim set up to deal with ANSI escape sequences).

The result isn't necessarily perfect, because the output of git-diff obviously isn't valid code in whatever programming language you're using, but it's close and easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to accomplish this depending on your system (PC, Mac, Linux) but if you're looking for a gui:

Mac: [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/)

PC: [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)

Linux: [Question already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux)